# Move ";" separated values to next line with Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any ideas how to display values from cell A1:

```
English; German; French; Spanish; Finnish; Russian
```

in this way using Excel formula?

```
  A2  English 
  A3  German 
  A4  French 
  A5  Spanish 
  A6  Finnish 
  A7  Russian
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in A2 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,";",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

`ROW(1:1)` is just a counter and should always be `1:1` for the first cell regardless of where the formula is placed or the reference cell.  It will move to `2:2` then `3:3` as it is copied down on its own.  It is how the formula knows which to return.

[image]

---

Once the dynamic array formulas have been released (Currently only available to Office Insiders) we can use SEQUENCE in place of ROW and only need to place the formula in the first cell without the need to copy down and Excel will fill in the rest:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""))+1,,0)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

---

To shorten the formula we can use a simple UDF to return an array of the values using `Split()`:

```
Function MYSPLIT(STR As String, del As String) As String()
    MYSPLIT = SPLIT(STR, del)
End Function
```

Then it is a simple INDEX formula:

```
=INDEX(MYSPLIT($A$1,";"),ROW(1:1))
```

And copy down.

Or when the Dynamic Arrays are released:

```
=TRASPOSE(MYSPLIT($A$1,";"))
```

In the first cell only.

Answer (score 4):

From Excel 2013 onwards, you can make use of [`FILTERXML`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). You can put this formula in `A2`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"; ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW(A1))
```

Drag down...

[image]

However, the other answer is less typing =)

Comment: with the new Dynamic Array formula, when introduced, placing `=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"; ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)` in the first cell returns the whole list without the need to copy down and is now shorter than mine. :)

Comment: Great solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you are using Excel 2010 Professional Plus or a later version of Excel, you can use **Power Query** to tackle this problem (however if you are only dealing with one cell or a small amount of data, this approach may be an overkill).

Firstly, load the data to the power query editor;

Secondly, highlight the relevant column, use **Split Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to split the values by delimiter semicolon `;`, and in the advanced setting select put the results into **Rows**. Then you should have the desired list.

Lastly close and load the output to a new worksheet (by default).

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume enter A1:

```
English; German; French; Spanish; Finnish; Russian
```

Then, copy `A1` and paste in `A2`

Select A2 >> Ctrl+H >> Find what : enter: "`;`" (without quote) >> Replace with : (keep blank) >> Press "Replace All" >> Close

A2 become :

```
English German French Spanish Finnish Russian
```

Reduce Column A width to wide: `8.00` (61 pixels)

Select `A2` >> `Editing` >> `Fill`, choose `Justify` >> OK >> Finish

Final become :

```
A2 English    
A3 German    
A4 French    
A5 Spanish    
A6 Finnish    
A7 Russian
```

Comment: As question says - how to do it with formula. Imagine your excel tool being used 1000 times by different people. How much time you would waste by using your solution to do all these operations?